# GRPC REST channel implementation

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

You can add REST "annotations" to a GRPC service: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding

I know there is a GRPC proxy service that you can run to proxy between GRPC <-> REST.

My question is, is there a GRPC channel implementation in Java that will allow me to achieve this without running a proxy service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gRPC Transcoding](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto#L46) is supported by Google APIs, Cloud Endpoint, gRPC Gateway and Envoy, but these annotations are not used by `protoc-gen-grpc-java`, so you have to either use a proxy service or implement support for these annotations yourself.

Comment: `so there is no way to get it working without a proxy service.` I don't believe this is true. I've hacked some code together to read the annotations at runtime to prove it was possible before posting the question - I was just hoping this had already been implemented...

Comment: @Cheetah of course, you can also patch the code generator and make it support these annotations. But what I mean is that this is not supported out of the box. Updated my answer to make it more straightforward.